# I lived on a small island for one year ten years ago

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

Is the following sentence grammatically correct and does it sound normal? Can we use two time adverbs in the same sentence as follows.

> I lived on a small island for one year *ten years ago*.
>
> *In 2010*, I lived on a small island for about/almost a year.
>
> *In 2010/ ten years ago*, I lived on a small island for a few/5 months.

Comment: Should be "a small island" -- want to edit it so as for it to be correct?

Comment: We are not supposed to be correcting your sentences, this is not an editing service. Would you say both in 2010 and il y a in French?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use those phrases like that. It might be clearer if you separate the time phrases:
"Ten years ago, I lived on a small island for one year."

(Note that usually, one says "on" an island, not "in".)

Comment: Thanks Jack, but as far as I know, we cannot add a specific date such as 2010 in this case, if we say for one year already. Is it correct?

Comment: "In 2010, I lived in France for one year."

Comment: @Mrt The OP didn't mention 2010. I guess you are asking a new question. You are now specifying the calendar year 2010. Your statement would not be exactly correct unless it meant from Jan 1,2010 to Dec 31, 2010. You could say "Around 2010, I lived in France for one year."

Comment: Thanks, I can edit my question if you like to include two choices.

Comment: @Mrt The only thing I would add is that you could say "In 2010, I lived in France for about/almost a year." You can edit your question if you like; maybe you would get some more answers.

Comment: In practice, people are more likely to say: **I lived in France for most of 2010.** or **I spent most of 2010 living in France.**

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks for suggestions but your sentences are applicable if we use "one year" as in my example sentences. However, I tried to ask if we can use a specific date and "for a while" adverbs in the same sentence. I can write another example to make it clear

Comment: @RonaldSole "In 2010/ ten years ago , I lived in France for a few/ 5  months."

Comment: @Mrt  Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Can you edit your answer accoding to my editing in the question please. Then I will accept your answer.